# Rails: how to sanitize nested object to save to JSONB column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Given these strong parameters in a Rails controller:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(details: [{ group: %i[type value] }])
end
```

How do I sanitize the `details` array before it's persisted into a JSONB column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a solution for anyone else with a similar problem:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

# ...

private

def sanitize_details
  return unless details

  self.details = details.map do |group|
    sanitized_details = group['group'].map do |detail|
      { type: sanitize_most(detail['type']), value: sanitize_most(detail['value']) }
    end
    { group: sanitized_details }
  end
end

def sanitize_most(field)
  sanitize(field, tags: %w[a b i strong em], attributes: %w[href rel target])
end
```